# problemas com rotas em JS + handlebars (ReferenceError: home is not defined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, rotas

estou aprendendo node.js, mas me enrolando demais em estabelecer as rotas corretamente.

A estrutura da minha pasta se encontra assim atualmente

[image: estrutura das pastas]

O código do arquivo server.js se encontra assim:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const hbs = require('express-handlebars')
const path = require('path')
const pdf = require('html-pdf')

//template
//app.engine('handlebars',hbs())
app.engine('handlebars',hbs({
    layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts',
    }));

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
//app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('home', {layout: 'main'})
    pdf.create(home, options).toFile("conclusao.pdf", (err, data)=>{
        return response.send("Erro ao gerar o PDF")
    })
})

const discentes = [
    {
        name: "Suaziele Cristina de Souza",
        age: 21,
        courseData: "21/12/2020",
        date: "10/06/2021",  
        obs: "Graduada em Ciência da Computaçâo."
    },
];

app.listen(3000)
```

A intenção era conectar a página inicial "home.handlebars" e exibir seu conteúdo.

OBS: o arquivo "main.handlebars" possui apenas esse código

```
{{{body}}}
```

Desde já agradeço a atenção dessa comunidade que tanto já me ajudou e continua ajudando a quem estuda programação.

Comment: `pdf.create(` Mas aqui você quer converter uma página em pdf. para exibir, página html dá uma olhada nessa respposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/37299711/6754506. E esse home não foi declarado em nenhum outro lugar

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma pasta com o nome de pages dentro das views, mova o home.handlebars para dentro dela, e teste esse código, o que fiz foi apenas mudar o layout do handlebars e o render.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
const path = require('path')
const pdf = require('html-pdf')

//template
//app.engine('handlebars',hbs())
app.engine('handlebars',handlebars({
     defaultLayout: "main"
    }));

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')

//app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render("pages/home")
    pdf.create(home, options).toFile("conclusao.pdf", (err, data)=>{
        return response.send("Erro ao gerar o PDF")
    })
})

const discentes = [
    {
        name: "Suaziele Cristina de Souza",
        age: 21,
        courseData: "21/12/2020",
        date: "10/06/2021",  
        obs: "Graduada em Ciência da Computaçâo."
    },
];

app.listen(3000)
```

Teste e veja se funciona agora